# Email not present in IDToken from Google Auth

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin

I'm trying to get the email from the IDToken returned by Google, this code has actually worked perfectly for months, until yesterday night.
Nothing was changed, and now for some devices, the Token doesn't contain the email.

I tried checking the OAuth2 playground for the same same accounts, and for all of them, the token provided by the playground actually has the email inside it.

On my phone, with the same account, it's not there.
I still get the name, account_id and stuff, only the email is missing.

On a colleague's phone, for the same account, the token contains the email.

The code for building the api　client:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            .addScope(new Scope("email"))
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .requestServerAuthCode(SERVER_ID, this)
            .build();
```

If this was only my phone this wouldn't be so much of a problem, but the fact that it happens unpredictably on 1 phone means that it can't be relied upon.

I'd like to know if there's a 100% guaranteed way to make sure the IDToken will always contain the email.

Note: I tried the people.get endpoint, but it didn't fix this issue, and completely blocked some accounts from even receiving a token at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are requesting the email scope, email should be inside the idtoken. We definitely would like to debug the issue. Can you ping me with some information (through hangout) so we try to have a look?